# How do I display a toast message depending on user input?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, radio-button

I have difficulty displaying specific conditional messages. I have questions with "yes" or "no" radio buttons for each question, so if the user answers "yes" to all questions they get a message saying they can apply. And if they answer any of the questions "no" they get a message saying "not eligible to apply". How do I check if the user has answered "no" and display the appropriate message.

I have recently started using Ionic-Angular so any guidance would be helpful.

survey.page.html

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle><p>Find out if you can apply</p></ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>

<ion-card-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group value="age">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Are you 20 - 45 of age?</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="yes" ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="No" ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>

    <ion-radio-group value="job-search">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Are you currently looking for work?</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="yes"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>

    <ion-button type="button" (click)= "displayMessage()" >Can I apply?</ion-button>

 </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

survey.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import  {FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './survey.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey.page.scss'],
})
export class survey implements OnInit {

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async displayMessage() {

    if ('No') {
      const toast1 = await this.toastController.create({
        message: `You are not eligible to apply`,
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'middle',
      });
      toast1.present();
    }else{
      const toast2 = await this.toastController.create({
        message: `You can apply`,
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'middle',
      });
      toast2.present();

    }

  }
}
```

**this is my edited survey.page.ts file**

```
export class survey  {

//gave it a type string due to errors
  radio1: string;
  radio2: string;


  constructor(public toastController: ToastController) { }


   onRadio1Change(event: any){
    this.radio1 = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.radio1);
  }

onRadio2Change(event: any){
    this.radio2 = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.radio2);
  }

  async displayMessage() {

    if (this.radio1 == "yes" && this.radio2 =="yes") {
      const toast1 = await this.toastController.create({
        message: `You can apply`,
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'middle',
      });
      toast1.present();
    }
else{
      const toast2 = await this.toastController.create({
        message: `You are not eligible to apply`,
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'middle',
      });
      toast2.present();

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this on your HTML:

```
<ion-radio-group value="age" (change)="onRadio1Change($event)">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Are you 20 - 45 of age?</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="yes" ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="No" ></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>

 <ion-radio-group value="job-search" (change)="onRadio2Change($event)">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Are you currently looking for work?</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="yes"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

then on your .ts file,

```
onRadio1Change(event:any){
    this.radio1 = event.target.value; 
    console.log(this.radio1)
  }

onRadio2Change(event:any){
    this.radio2 = event.target.value; 
    console.log(this.radio2)
  }
...

//then create an if statement
if (this.radio1 == "yes" && this.radio2 =="yes"){
   //your success toast
}
else {
   //your fail test
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it is giving error for radio1 & radio2 "error: Property 'radio1' does not exist on type". I have it given it type string which solved the errors "radio1: string;". However, the form is only presenting the failed test case message

Comment: Share your .ts file with the new code I wrote above

Comment: I have posted the .ts file underneath my original post